# Status page shows "Mismatched Entity.." for a Paragraph field but Drush entup give error "..storage cannot change the schema for an existing field"

Tags: drush, paragraphs

I'm stuck in a loop. The Drupal 9.3 status page shows the following error:

```
Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.
Paragraph
The paragraph.field_heading field needs to be updated.
```

When I run `drush entup` I get the below error. I have a lot of data in the mentioned field so I can't delete the field. How did this mismatch happen and why can't `entup` resolve it?

Comment: The messages says you need an update hook migrating the data. Since the module for the entity type Paragraphs provides update hooks for schema changes the problem is probably caused by the field definition. How is the field defined and what changed before the error?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "How is the field defined?" - it's a plain text field used on several Paragraph entities. I've re-saved the fields and Paragraphs everywhere the field is used without any change in the error.

Comment: You mean the core plain text field type, the field name is shared between different paragraph types and you are trying to re-save the field settings of paragraph types? Then this is the same as in a content type and is not paragraph specific. But why are people using plain text fields all the time without a schema mismatch? There has to be something special in your case, for example did you try to change the text field length?

Comment: Ahhh, I did change the text field length. Wow, I forgot about that. With this new information do you have any suggestions on how to fix the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*With this new information do you have any suggestions on how to fix the error?*

This schema mismatch in a plain text field doesn't normally happen. You can't change the maximum length in UI, it's not allowed if the field contains data. And you can't import a modified field storage definition, this throws the same error as above and stops the import. So it's unclear how you did this, but the fix is then to use the same way to change it back.

---

*Why can't entup resolve it?*

See https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates

Comment: Thank you, I found my original documentation and the article with the update hook code to change a field length. I found an issue in the code, fixed reran the update hook and the issue is resolved now.